# Definir el tamaño de un lienzo en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, opengl

Tengo un problema al hacer una figura 3D en Android. Estoy haciendo un cubo en 3D y lo quiero mostrar dentro de un fragmento, el cubo ya se muestra y ya tiene animacion, el problema es que me cubre toda la pantalla y estoy usando un navigation drawer el problema es que ya no me permite hacer uso de mi drawer por que lo cubre por completo, como puedo definir el ancho del lienzo para mi cubo.

Esta es la forma en la que se ve mi cubo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Normalmente mi aplicacion deberia tener un cajo de navegacion como el siguiente, pero al momento de pasar al fragmento que contiene la figura 3D el cajon se cubre por completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi Fragmento donde muestro el cubo:

```
/**
 * Created by Enriq on 01/06/2018.
 */

public class graficosFragmento extends Fragment {

    private GLSurfaceView lienzo;
    private RelativeLayout real;

    public graficosFragmento(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        lienzo = new GLSurfaceView(getContext());
        lienzo.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(getContext()));

        getActivity().setContentView(lienzo);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_graficos, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase cubo, donde defino las carectiristicas de mi cubo:

```
**
 * Created by Enriq on 01/06/2018.
 */

public class Cubo {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer texturaBuffer;

    int[] texturaIDs = new int[1];

    private float texturaCoord[] = {
            0.0f, 0.5f,
            0.5f,0.5f,
            0.0f,0.0f,
            0.5f,0.0f
    };

    private int numCaras = 6;

    private float[] vertices = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    public Cubo(){
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texturaCoord.length*4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texturaBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        texturaBuffer.put(texturaCoord);
        texturaBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void dibujar(GL10 gl){
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, texturaBuffer);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0.0f ,0.5f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0.0f ,0.5f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f ,0.5f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0.5f ,0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0.5f ,0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.f, 0.5f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public void cargarTextura(GL10 gl, Context context){
        gl.glGenTextures(1, texturaIDs, 0);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturaIDs[0]);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.metal);

        Bitmap bitmap;

        try{
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
        }finally {
            try{
                istream.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

}
```

Y por ultimo esta es mi clase donde hago el render:

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Cubo cubo;
    private Context context;

    private static float anguloCubo = 0;
    private static float speedCubo = -1.5f;

    public MyRenderer(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        cubo = new Cubo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        cubo.cargarTextura(gl,context);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
        gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
        gl.glRotatef(anguloCubo,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

        cubo.dibujar(gl);

        anguloCubo += speedCubo;
    }
}
```

Como puedo hacer para que mi cajon de navegacion no sea cubierto por mi lienzo donde dibujo el cubo.

Estoy intentando agregar un onBackPressed() para poder volver al fragment anterior pero me muestra un error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(int)' on
>   a null object reference

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

```
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else { 
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Y al fragmento le añadie esto: **.addToBackStack(null)**

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe,graficos).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: El menú se abre pero puede volver a ocultarse. Quisieras que el menú fuera más pequeño para que siempre se vea el cubo?, en realidad creo que como lo tienes actualmente es buena opción.

Comment: @Jorgesys mas bien quiero que el fondo negro que en teoria es mi lienzo sea mas pequeño por que mi cajon ya no se abre ni se muestra.

Comment: @Jorgesys creo que lo mas facil seria programar el boton de retroceso en Android para que me devuelva al fragmento anterior, pero comopuedo hacerlo? me da un error si le añdo .addToBackStack("animacion")

Comment: agrega el código de lo que tratas y comenta que error tienes para dar una solución.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo agregue

Comment: no es necesario agregarlo al backStack, simplemente: manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe,graficos).commit();

Comment: @Jorgesys si lo hago de sa forma me da el siguiente error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(int)' on a null object reference